# Find count of unique values in columns based on date in column 1

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have 3 comma separated quoted fields.

```
last crawled,linking page,domain
"Nov 17, 2018","https://allestoringen.be/problemen/bwin/antwerpen","allestoringen.be"
"Aug 11, 2017","http://casino.linkplek.be/","linkplek.be"
"Nov 17, 2018","http://pronoroll.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_26.html","pronoroll.blogspot.com"
etc
```

I need to remove duplicates on the date fields and find the count of unique linking pages for each unique date (column $2) and count of unique domains for the unique date (column $3). I have tried :

```
awk '{A[$1 OFS $2]++} END {for(k in A) print k, A[k]}' FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' file
awk '{A[$1 OFS $3]++} END {for(k in A) print k, A[k]}' FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' file
```

But I am a little confused on getting all 3 columns in a single go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# script.awk

BEGIN {
    FPAT = "[^\"]+"
}

{
    # the first if is to avoid processing title row and rows that do not contain fields
    if (NF > 1) {
        # the third field is the linking page column; the second field is a comma
        if ($3 != "" && $1 $3 in unique_linking_pages == 0) {
            unique_linking_pages[$1 $3]
            unique_linking_page_counts[$1]++
        }
        # the fifth field is the domain column; the fourth field is a comma
        if ($5 != "" && $1 $5 in unique_domains == 0) {
            unique_domains[$1 $5]
            unique_domain_counts[$1]++
        }

        # in case of empty fields in columns 2 and or 3 of the input file,
        # this ensures that all the dates are recorded
        dates[$1]
    }
}

END {
    printf "Date, Unique Linking Page Count, Unique Domain Count\n"
    for (date in dates)
        output = output date " | " unique_linking_page_counts[date] " | " unique_domain_counts[date] "\n"

    system("column -t -s '|' <<< '" output "'")
}
```

Comment: @NikoGambt..can the output be in the form of: 
date, unique_linking_page_counts, unique_domain_counts
No pages or domains...just counts

Comment: So, for example, even though `Nov 17, 2018` has two unique linking pages, you want the `unique_linking_page_counts` to be equal to `2` for that date?? The only way to do what you're asking is to group the unique linking pages by date (and to group the unique domains by date too). However, doing so would lose the information of what linking pages (and domains) are unique!

Comment: Yes....I want to get only unique dates, ie. Nov 17, 2018 appears once and number of unique linking pages will be 2 as in this case...this is true for domains as well.

Comment: @MallikKumar Just an advice, you should have provided an example output in your OP. No one has the superpower to guess what you want. Just like me, anybody can misunderstand what you want.

Comment: My mistake. Should have put one in my post. Appreciate your help in this matter.

Comment: @MallikKumar I've just updated my answer. Something like this problem would be better off to be solved using a database language like SQL.

Comment: Would add +1 if I could. Wonderful answer!!